# Log file empty while creating a custom log for a cluster using the Wildfly Clustering API

Tags: logging, wildfly

I'm using WildFly 12.0 Final to form a cluster in domain mode and I also tried to use the Clustering API to make a log file with only useful information about the cluster.

The file cluster.log is created but it's empty.

The class that I made looks like this:

```
package com.cluster.logger;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.wildfly.clustering.group.GroupListener;
import org.wildfly.clustering.group.Membership;
import org.wildfly.clustering.group.Node;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class ClusterListener implements GroupListener
{

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ClusterListener.class);

@Override
public void membershipChanged(Membership previousMembership, Membership newMembership, boolean merged)
{

    List<Node> previousNodes = previousMembership.getMembers();

    LOG.infof("========================================");
    LOG.infof("= Information about the previous nodes =");
    for (Node node : previousNodes)
    {
        LOG.infof("Node name: " + node.getName());
        LOG.infof("Node address: " + node.getSocketAddress());
    }
    LOG.infof("========================================");

    List<Node> newNodes = newMembership.getMembers();

    LOG.infof("========================================");
    LOG.infof("=== Information about the new nodes ====");
    for (Node node : newNodes)
    {
        LOG.infof("Node name: " + node.getName());
        LOG.infof("Node address: " + node.getSocketAddress());
    }
    LOG.infof("========================================");

    LOG.infof("Are they merged?: " + merged);
    LOG.infof("========================================");
}
}
```

I also created a custom WildFly module to configure this class and also modified the logging subsystem in domain.xml to handle everything and the .jar file is in the same folder as the module.xml file.

This is the module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.cluster.logger">
     <resources>
           <resource-root path="ClusterLogger.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <dependencies>
          <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
          <module name="javax.api"/>
          <module name="org.wildfly.clustering"/>
     </dependencies>
</module>
```

This is the configuration in domain.xml

```
<size-rotating-file-handler name="CLUSTER-LOG">
      <formatter>
           <named-formatter name="CLUSTER-PATTERN"/>
      </formatter>
      <file relative-to="jboss.home.dir" path="cluster.log"/>
      <rotate-size value="10m"/>
      <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</size-rotating-file-handler>
...
<logger category="com.cluster.logger">
      <level name="TRACE"/>
      <handlers>
          <handler name="CLUSTER-LOG"/>
      </handlers>
</logger>
...
<formatter name="CLUSTER-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the log statements end up in the `server.log`?

Comment: I took you after missing part of your long config, you haven't attached to the root

Comment: The logs don't go anyware, James, its just empty.

As for the root, if I use the same configuration but say I use a different logger category like "org.infinispan.topology" the info is actually writen to cluster.log
So i'm not sure if I have something else that i'm not looking at.

Sorry for the delay, I was busy and didn't take a look but i'm still trying to find the solution.